# "'Bumping' question after editing" feature should be removed

Tags: feature-request, edits, bump

It happened to me lots of times. I enjoy editing old posts, and sometimes I edit dozens of them an hour. However, some people start complaining that I pollute their 'front page' (this means 'Active' tab on question list). But I do not have the slightest intention to do this, and I have no real idea why would these two things be linked at all.

It is the same situation as following:

- You enter your house, turn on the light, and microwave oven automatically turns on.
- You turn on vipers in your car, and climate control turns on too.
- You press desired floor in an elevator in a building, and suddenly the whole building starts flashing with various lights.
- You flush the water in a toilet, and that triggers launching space shuttle in Florida.

Please remove that 'bumping' feature, and maybe leave checkbox 'Bump' for people who REALLY want to bump the question.

Comment: [Bump](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/bump/info)s _are_ annoying, but getting rid of them would be too easy to abuse by any of 30,000 users having edit privileges.

Answer (score 24):

> It is the same situation as following:

No, it isn't. Bumping has a purpose.

The reason editing posts bumps them to the front page is to give other readers an opportunity to review the posts that were edited, as well as the edits, in context, especially if the edits are substantial.

Instead of removing a useful feature, I suggest you simply only edit posts that are in need of editing and put more time and effort into making your edits more substantial, instead of doing things like [creating a brand new tag and then adding it to a bunch of old questions that have lived just fine without it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sunburst-diagram?sort=active). This way, the posts continue to get bumped and get more eyeballs, but the edits are more substantial and spaced apart, so bumping happens less frequently, and nobody will complain about their front pages getting flooded with minor edits.

Comment: Perhaps "wow what a load of crap" is not the best way to express disagreement.

Comment: @Keith Thompson: Yeah, you're right. I should probably go do something else - today just isn't my day.

Comment: Looks like somebody is going for taxonomist....

Comment: It's a tough badge to get on a mature site.

Answer (score 15):

We could the option to mark a edit as "minor" (like in wikipedia)
should be available to higher rep editors.

A minor edit could be restricted to say retagging, and perhaps some other algorithmically recognisable changes.

We could have a Minor edit review list/page, containing the last ~15 minor edits per page.
Like a second front page where only minor edit questions are shown.

Or we could have a flag that you can check in preferences saying:
"Show questions that have been updated by minor edits",
that would for the interested user show them on their front pages.

and the ability (at a certain rep) to unmark a edit as minor.

#### Use case:

On RPG.SE we are cleaning up [a tag that has been heavily misused](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4869/burninate-new-gm-tag/4893#4893).
Over 100 questions will have the tags removed.
Some of them will have other improvements made.
Most won't need it.

Answer (score 9):

By bumping every question I edit, you are in effect trying to tell me which questions to edit. You are trying to tell me to only edit questions you want to have bumped.

How about, once I reach, say, 10k+, I am allowed to edit questions you would not want to have bumped. How about you let me edit whatever questions I want to edit, without polluting your front page.

You have a "separation of concerns" problem here. Editing should not always equate to bumping.

Answer (score 3):

#### Don't stop bumping, just make sure *everyone* doesn't see *every* bump

Copied from my comment on [another post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/379755/9209546):

> A better idea is to limit / cap how many of these minor edits get
>   bumped for each user and try and ensure different users see different
>   bumps (maybe each user only sees 20% of these edits). If that's too
>   much effort, make it a random 20%. This way at least there are some
>   eyes on each bumped post, and recurrent spammers will get caught out,
>   while still not ruining the user experience. Spammers usually target
>   popular posts in popular tags, so this will probably work.