# Minor edits to old questions should not cause them to show up in "interesting" list

Tags: discussion

As a more casual user, interested in some of the less popular tags, I often find some old questions popping into my "interesting" list (on the default page), for example:

[View all work-spaces associated with TFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28606832) is a 2.5 year old question, and it's only had 18 views right now. Some minor edits were made an hour ago, and the tags were updated, and it pushed it into my feed even though it's not been otherwise updated since Feb 2015.

Some more from my "interesting" cat:

[How to manage one giant TFS team project which has multiple projects in JIRA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29341994) (2 years 4 months)
[Can't create more team projects after update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31593834) (2 years)
[How to filter TFS contributors to a specific project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31851241) (1 year 11 months)

While I appreciate the work of people updating categories, spelling, etc., it shouldn't really be finding its way into the "interesting" category.  Possibly when editing the post this should be seen as an option to not mark it as active "today".

Comment: I do think they should do a minor/major edit like they do on documentation.  Tag only edits should not bump the post and if you just go through and clean up some spelling and grammar that is also not a reason to bump the post.

Comment: Having an edit option that that hides the recently-active status might lead to spam edits not being found quickly. @NathanOliver's idea on tag-only edits might be an exception.

Comment: Related - [“'Bumping' question after editing” feature should be removed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262813/bumping-question-after-editing-feature-should-be-removed) Also, [Should formatting a question or answer always bump to front page?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74401/should-formatting-a-question-or-answer-always-bump-to-front-page?rq=1)

Comment: This is why I always use the "newest" tab and never the "active" tab.

Comment: What about "don't bump if minor edits AND there are answers"? What if someone is interested in an old question without answers? Should they ask a duplicate question or "bump" the existing one improving even by a bit?

Comment: What about if y'all use the features on the site to do what you want? [New questions asked today](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request?filter=today), [needing answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request?filter=need-answers), etc.

Comment: @Braiam Yes, but this happens on the default page when, the "interesting" category only appears here, and it's a default.  I do usually look through the other categories, but putting a 2+ year old question with nothing other than cosmetic updates into "interesting" isn't very, erm, interesting! As a niche user, most (nearly all) of my highlighted questions from yesterday were in fact junk.

Comment: @DanielMorritt that's not a fault of the system... if you keep feeding it crap questions, obviously it would show you crap questions.

Comment: @Braiam That's not quite right though, I follow some niche topics, in this case it's TFS (as you could tell from the questions I linked), seeing questions on TFS isn't a problem, I _want_ to see those questions, but someone re-categorising _old_ TFS questions that haven't been updated in 2 years causing them to show up as "interesting" _is_ bad.  The questions themselves aren't "bad", just unpopular enough they don't get any mainstream interest or many answers.