# Is there a way to prevent edits to "Old" questions from showing up in the "Top Questions" list?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, edits, bump

Here is the situation. A user is doing a very good thing and is helping improve the quality of old questions by fixing misspellings or capitalization, etc...

The rub is that every non-consequential edit bumps the question (that may be 5+ years old and already answered) back onto the Stack Overflow "Top Questions" list (e.g., *[When you divide a hexadecimal, what do you get?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28773901/when-you-divide-a-hexadecimal-what-do-you-get)*).

When this happens to 20+ questions in a short period of time, this causes the "Top Questions" list to be flooded by old, already answered, posts.

Is there a way to prevent these type of edits to old, answered questions from putting them back on the "Top Questions" list?

It would be a great new feature to add. I've seen numerous comments added to these old questions -- before they snap to the fact they just commented on a "zombie post".

Comment: Yes, it appears to be, although that duplicate was horribly presented in terms of "flushing toilets", etc.. that seem to have largely detracted from it. However, the answer discussing using "[ ] minor edit" to prevent the bump has merit. Should I just delete this or vote it as a duplicate?

Comment: Here's another one that went nowhere: [Minor edits to old questions should not cause them to show up in “interesting” list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354119) and cross-site request on MSE: [Should formatting a question or answer always bump to front page?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74401/should-formatting-a-question-or-answer-always-bump-to-front-page). Since your feature request would affect all sites on the Network, perhaps you should add your argument for this feature as an answer on the MSE question

Comment: I wonder why neither showed when I typed my question title in. I went though the entire list to make sure I wasn't duping an old thread. Maybe the "Top Questions" skewed the results list. What do you think the best for this question is? "Delete it / Vote to Close as a Dup"?

Comment: I searched for "[edit bumping](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=edit%20bumping%20is%3aq)" - I'm very sure there is more than one duplicate. We could probably leave your open for new discussion if you can amend it adding additional compelling reasons for this request.

Comment: OK, I don't know what more I would add. It's really just the minor changes like fixing the `"dont"` to `"don't"` and `"i"` to `"I"` like was done in the link I posted, that are very good things to fix, but that really shouldn't bump the question back to the "Top Questions" list. I wonder if there is some type of scoring of edits that would consider the age of the question and could ignore whitespace, character case and punctuation changes that could help?

Comment: I like the idea of flagging something as a minor edit (like Wikipedia does) and not bumping those up. We could rely on the editor to flag it. I don’t see any incentive for gaming this.

Comment: Tangentially related: [What to do about mass edits of old questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/207330)

Comment: Did you mean to tag this with \[[meta-tag:feature-request]\] rather than \[[meta-tag:feature-request-process]\]?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I messed that up - updated.

Answer (score 4):

This is in fact a bad idea. The bump is done in case answer or edit put spam on it, and is for getting it checked.

I think the idea of the new edit tags is for getting rid of the bump when just tags change as that pretty much can't be spam.

Comment: While there is merit in making sure we didn't get spammed, elevating that concern above basic usability and now spamming the "Top Questions" list with dozens long ago answered and dormant questions seems a little harsh. It seems like one of the top tech sites should be able to discriminate between possible vandalism/spam and someone changing an `"i"` to and `"I"` or a `"dont"` to a `"don't"`. Somehow I think there is a better balance that could be struck.

Comment: A better idea is to *limit / cap* how many of these minor edits get bumped for each user and try and ensure different users see different bumps (maybe each user only sees 20% of these edits). If that's too much effort, make it a random 20%. This way at least there are *some* eyes on each bumped post, and recurrent spammers will get caught out, while still not ruining the user experience. Spammers usually target popular posts in popular tags, so this will probably work.